# Finding the place where auto-fill-mode is getting enabled and disabling it

Tags: html

So, whenever I open a new buffer, `auto-fill-mode` is enabled. I have checked my configuration and have verified that I'm not enabling it in the `init.el` file. How do I find out from where it is getting enabled ?

Also, how do I disable it in a certain mode like html-mode. I tried some [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878623/how-can-i-disable-auto-fill-mode-in-emacs) in this thread but this doesn't seem to work for me:

```
(remove-hook 'html-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I usually do is look at the doc string first and search for "hook". This gives me `html-mode-hook` and the hooks of its parents. Search for "parent" and this gives me `sgml-mode`. Keep repeating. I end up with:

1. `html-mode-hook`
2. `sgml-mode-hook`
3. `text-mode-hook`

Still in the `*Help*` buffer, you can click on all of those and see what's there. In my case, I see `turn-on-auto-fill` on `text-mode-hook`. The solution was this:

```
(add-hook 'html-mode-hook 'turn-off-auto-fill)
```

Text Mode will have auto-fill enabled and HTML Mode will have auto-fill disabled. You could argue that I probably don't want SGML Mode to have auto-fill enabled, but since I don't use it, I don't care. :)

**Looking at Doc Strings**: If it's a function, use `C-h f`. If it's a variable, use `C-h v`. If you don't know what your major mode is, examine the *variable* `major-mode` using  `C-h v`. This should tell you the major mode such as `html-mode`. This is a *function*, so you need to use `C-h f`.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. Can you also add how you see `doc strings` ?

Comment: Sure. No problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can get Emacs to show you a stack trace when the function is called, so that you can figure out what called it.

1. <kbd>M-x</kbd> `debug-on-entry` <kbd>RET</kbd> `auto-fill-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>
2. *trigger the issue*
3. Check the stack trace. Depending on the details, the *exact* cause may not be 100% clear, but it should certainly give you a good idea of where to look next.
4. Use <kbd>c</kbd> to continue execution of the function, or <kbd>q</kbd> to quit the debugger.
5. <kbd>M-x</kbd> `cancel-debug-on-entry` <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>RET</kbd>

The documentation for the debugger is in the manual:

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Debugger` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Be sure to read the "Debugger Commands" node.